# How do I completely reset all Heroku CLI settings? Old account keeps messing permissions when I git-push, even after heroku logout

Tags: git, heroku

Even after doing `heroku logout`, re-installing heroku, and adding the `accounts` plugin with only my work account, I keep getting the following message when I try to `git push heroku master`:

```
Your account <email of old account> does not have access to <app>
```

Is there a way to completely reset all my heroku settings?

Answer (score 0):

The accounts plugin makes some changes to your ssh config which can cause this problem.

Probably the default ssh-key (~/.ssh/id_rsa on a mac/linux) is connected to the heroku account registered with .

You can solve the problem by either disconnecting the key to the old account or by making sure you have another ssh key connected to your new account and then adding the following rule to ~/.ssh/config.

```
Host heroku.com
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<another-key-file>
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys